# If a state operator factors, then it factors into partial state operators in particular -- why?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, density-operator, quantum-states

Suppose that we have a state operator for a bipartite quantum system $\rho = A \otimes B$. As far as I know, one must then have in particular $\rho^{(1)} = A$; that is, if a state operator factors then it factors in particular into partial state operators. Why is this?

When I try to prove it I try to use the definition
$$\rho^{(1)} = \sum_n A \langle b_n| B|b_n \rangle = A \sum_n\langle b_n| B|b_n \rangle,$$
but, per the last step, it would seem that I need to assume $B$ carries normalization ($\sum_n\langle b_n| B|b_n \rangle = 1$)? Why must this be?

Comment: Ah, I think I see. You are saying that *definitionally* $A$ and $B$ are density operators on their respective states. The normalization then follows @TobiasFünke

Comment: I would say my question is *does it follow that they are in particular the reduced state/partial density operators of each subsystem*. But I think my question might be ill-posed now that I think about it (not enough information about $A$ and $B$). @TobiasFünke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a (finite-dimensional, complex) bipartite Hilbert space $H=H_1\otimes H_2$ and let $\rho$ denote a generic density operator, i.e. a positive semi-definite operator of unit trace. Suppose $\rho=A\otimes B$ for operators $A$ on $H_1$ and $B$ on $H_2$. We ask whether these operators are also density operators (on their respective Hilbert spaces) and if so, if these coincide with the reduced density matrices of $\rho$.

The answer is that $A$ and $B$ are in general **not** density operators, and in particular not the reduced density matrices of $\rho$. Indeed, a straightforward calculation yields that the reduced density matrices are given by $\rho_1=A\,\mathrm{Tr}B$ and $\rho_2=B\,\mathrm{Tr}A$. From the respective trace normalizations we can simplify this to $\rho_1=\frac{A}{\mathrm{Tr}A}$ and $\rho_2=\frac{B}{\mathrm{Tr}B}$.

So the conclusion is that $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are trivially related to $A$ and $B$ and vice versa. Thus, if $\rho$ is a (simple) tensor product of operators, it can be written as the tensor product of its reduced density matrices.

Comment: Lovely, thank you! Presumably for trace-class operators there is a generalization?

Comment: @EE18 Good question. I guess so, but I am not a mathematician and haven't tried to formulate it rigorously in infinite dimension...

Comment: @EE18 sorry, there was an error in my argument! I have updated the answer...damn...The overall conclusion is still true, though. But I think one can derive some necessary conditions on $A$ and $B$ from that, which however are of no importance for the actual question. Sorry for the confusion.